# Get DOM node of wrapped component in a higher order component (HOC)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How do I get the DOM node of the rendered div from `MyComponent` inside `Enhance` in the following example?

**Enhance.js**

```
import { Component } from "React";

export var Enhance = ComposedComponent => class extends Component {
  constructor() {
    this.state = { data: null };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ data: 'Hello' });
  }
  render() {
    return <ComposedComponent {...this.props} data={this.state.data} />;
  }
};
```

**MyComponent.js**

```
import { Enhance } from "./Enhance";

class MyComponent {
  render() {
    if (!this.data) return <div>Waiting...</div>;
    return <div>{this.data}</div>;
  }
}

export default Enhance(MyComponent); // Enhanced component
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your HOC is rendering a child component directly, the data returned by `findDOMNode` in the HOC should be the child's DOM node.

```
export var Enhance = ComposedComponent => class extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        // Logs the DOM node returned by the wrapped component
        console.log( ReactDOM.findDOMNode( this.refs.child ) );
    }
    render() {
        return <ComposedComponent {...this.props} ref="child" />;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

The high order component is the wrapped component itself... enhanced.
Getting the dom node of the wrapped component is equivalent to get the dom node of the hoc.

```
export var Enhance = ComposedComponent => class extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        // Logs the DOM node returned by the wrapped component
        console.log( ReactDOM.findDOMNode( this ) );
    }
    render() {
        return <ComposedComponent {...this.props}  />;
    }
};
```

In this way I can also use forwardRef pattern

```
export default WrappedComponent => {
  class EnhancedComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
      const domNode = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this);
      console.log(domNode);
    }

    render() {
      const { forwardedRef, ...otherProps } = this.props;
      return <WrappedComponent ref={forwardedRef} {...otherProps} />;
    }
  }

  const forwardRef = (props, ref) => <EnhancedComponent {...props} forwardedRef={ref} />;
  return React.forwardRef(forwardRef);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`findDOMNode` usage appears to be frowned upon (https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/issues/678#issue-165177220) and `ref` string values I believe will be depreciated. You can still use `ref` and wrap your `ComposedComponent` in a `div` with a `ref`, allowing you to access the node.

```
<div ref={ (elem) => { this.elem = elem; } }>
    <ComposedComponent { ...this.props }  />
</div>
```

**EDIT**
Since you are using React Component classes, you don't need the wrapper. The wrapper is if it's a functional component.